# How to display the json data in ejs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a json data in a controller file and I got this data from an API so that I can be able 
    to redirect this data gotten from the API to an ejs file but when I write the code in the body tag part like 
    this <%-JSON.stringify(jsonData)%>, it will display the entire JSON  but when 
    I am using this statement under script tags I don't get anything but [object object] error message is what comes out.

How can I use this JSON data inside script tags for displaying each and every key/value pair from the JSON data? Can you anyone suggest an answer?

In Controller:

```
res.render('display', {
  jsonData: storeJSONData
});
```

I wrote this code for a redirecting template.

Comment: You should probably also show your `display` template.

Comment: Hi Sir this is my script code in tempate. <script  type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress(){
var data= <%-JSON.stringify(jsonData)%>

document.write(data);
}
</script> i called this function from body tag using <body onload="codeAddress()">

Comment: i got output on the browser [object Object] instead of json data why it is happen?i know <%- it renders the variables <%= it renders in html but still i didn't get the json data.

Answer (score 10):

No talk just watch :P

I have send data like this.

```
res.render('studentlist',{'studentlist' : result} );
```

Then I show those data in a table like this baby :D

```
<table class="table table-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% for(var i=0; i < studentlist.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= studentlist[i].name %></td>
      <td><%= studentlist[i].email %></td>
      <td><%= studentlist[i].username %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it will help you out there. I am pretty sure . :)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The following is the 'docs' that we pass from the controller to view.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    User.find((err, docs) =>{
    if(!err)
      res.render('home', {'docs':docs});    
    else
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});
```

And now we can use the variable docs to display on ejs templeate. Example

```
<ul class="collection">
 <% datas.forEach(function(data) { %>
    <li class="collection-item avatar">
      <span class="title"><%= data.name %></span>
      <p>First Line <br>
         <%= data.email %>
      </p>
    </li>
  <% }); %>
  </ul>
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this in your HTML and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress(){ 
         var data = <%- jsonData %>;
         document.write(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    }
</script>
```

This is because you can't use JS inside the EJS tags, you need to render it to be assigned to a `var` and then you can play with it.

Comment: Hi Sir i tried this one but i didn't get the json data sir function codeAddress(){
 alert("data");
  var data = <%- jsonData %>;
         document.write(JSON.stringify(data)); 

} when i comment last two lines then "data" value will be displayed in pop-up but when i uncomment last two lines even pop-up message is not displayed and json data also not.

Comment: In both cases either in comment or uncomment the json won't be displayed.how can i get this json data?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `render()` to:

```
res.render('display', {
  jsonData: JSON.stringify(storeJSONData)
});
```

and your template to:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress() {
  var data = <%- jsonData %>;
  document.write(data);
}
</script>
```