# Want to display JSON data from an API call by clicking a button, while using EJS, express, and axios

Tags: html, node.js, express, axios, ejs

I am trying to display JSON data using EJS. The JSON data is coming from an URL, in which I am using axios to get the data from. So far, I have a server.js file to get the data and render the pages, and two pages titled index.ejs and loaded.ejs. The index file will simply contain a button that will be clicked to display the JSON data onto the loaded.ejs page. I'm having trouble getting the data to show on the loaded.ejs page. No matter what I have tried so far when I load the loaded.ejs page it shows either blank or displays [object Object]. I'm very new to this and just need a little guidance in the right direction and where I'm going wrong.

The code below is where I currently am. I am trying to get the data from the URL to display, but the output of the loaded.ejs file returns [object Object].

Server.js file

```
// required module to make calls to a REST API
const axios = require('axios');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("pages/index.ejs", {});
});

app.post('/process_form', function(req, res){
    var url = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams";
    axios.get(url)
        .then((response)=>{
            let teams = response.data;
            res.render('pages/loaded.ejs', {
                team: teams
            });
        });
  
  })




app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

Index.ejs file

```
<header>
    
</header>

<main>
<div>
    <form action="/process_form" method="post">
        <h2>Click button below to show Hockey Teams</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</main>


<footer>

</footer>
```

Loaded.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>

</head>
<body class="container">

    <header>
        
    </header>

    <main>
        <% if (locals.team) { %>
            <p> <%= team %> </p>
        <% } %>

    </main>

    <footer>
        
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

although your question seems to be a duplicate to [How to display the json data in ejs template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889807/how-to-display-the-json-data-in-ejs-template?rq=2), here's how you can go about this.

First, you're getting [object Object] because you're trying to render an object as a string which for sure isn't what you want.

So, to resolve...you start by studying the object returned by the API you're calling. A quick load of the API in the browser shows the object structure (`teams = response.data` yeilds an object and inside of it is an array of object called `teams`)...so, using this structure in mind and the current way your server code is written, here's how your `loaded.ejs` can be reformatted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>

</head>
<body class="container">

    <header>
        
    </header>

    <main>
        <% if (team && team.teams) { %>
        <% for (const t of team.teams) { %>
            <div>
              <p>Team Name <%= t.name %> </p>
              <p>Division <%= t.division.name %> </p>
              <p>Venue <%= t.venue.name %> </p>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>

    </main>

    <footer>
        
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I removed `locals` because the `team` variable dynamically becomes available within ejs's scope after the call to the `res.render()` function.

Also, since there are many ways you might choose to render your data, my illustration above is just a subtle guide as you have requested in your question.